# Python Web crawler Index Error for Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
# 일베 일간 베스트 크롤링 코드
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import re
import pandas as pd

def crawling_comment(title, titleList, commentList):
    # 게시글 페이지 파싱
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    comments = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : re.compile('comment_\d+ xe_content')})
    for n in range(len(comments)):
        titleList.append(title)
        commentList.append(comments[n].get_text().replace('\n',''))

driver_path = "D:/jhPark/ilbe-crawling/driver/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)

# 일베 일간 베스트 페이지 이동
url_page = 'http://www.ilbe.com/ilbe'
driver.get(url_page)

Titles = []
Comments = []  

page = 1
pageNum = 4

# 사이트 main 크롤링
while page < 1000:
    # 타이틀 페이지 파싱
    html1 = driver.page_source
    titlePage = BeautifulSoup(html1, "lxml")

    # 해당 페이지의 모든 제목을 담음
    tempTitles = titlePage.find_all('td', {'class' : re.compile('title bdoc_\d+')})

    for n in range(1000):
        # 이미 크롤링한 제목이면 패스
        tempTitle = tempTitles[n].find('a').get_text().replace('\n','')
        if tempTitle in Titles: continue
        else:
            while True:
                try:
                    print(n, tempTitle)
                    # 해당 게시글로 이동
                    time.sleep(1)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/form/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[2]/a'.format(n+5)).click()
                    break
                except:
                    break

            # 댓글 크롤링 함수 호출
            crawling_comment(tempTitle, Titles, Comments)
            driver.back()

    # 다음 페이지 이동
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(2)
            if pageNum < 9:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/a[{}]'.format(pageNum)).click()
                pageNum += 1
            else:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/a[{}]'.format(pageNum)).click()
            page += 1
            print('{}페이지 크롤링 완료, 댓글 {}개 수집'.format(page, len(Comments)))
            break
        except:
            break
```

This is the web crawler you downloaded, and you will see the error below. What should I do?
The error is as below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\ilbe-crawling.py", line 42, in <module>
    tempTitle = tempTitles[n].find('a').get_text().replace('\n','')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Which part should be modified to operate normally without causing this error?

Is there any way to crawl comments from the site other than the above code?

If you have any other method or code, I would appreciate it if you could show me.

Answer (score 0):

`for n in range(1000)` 
it s this line most likely, you are indexing all the way up to 1000, this only works if the item you are indexint in to has a length of atleast 1001. try changing it to for n in `range(len(tempTitles))`